# What options for analytics dashboards are out there besides leftronic.com?

Tags: analytics, dashboard

We have analytics coming from several different services and need a place to combine all the data in a single display. Does anyone have experience with other services besides leftronic.com?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We've used Leftronic and were quite satisfied with the product, but have since moved onto [Geckoboard](http://www.geckoboard.com/) because the UI is much more elegant. You might also want to checkout [Boarrd](http://boarrd.com/).

Comment: This was just a BS question to get some stackoverflow points so that I could answer and vote. Within an hour, one of Leftronic's co-founders found me on linkedin and sent me a personal message.

For anyone who may actually come across this thread, leftronic has a solid product. Their API for posting streams is really simple and their servers are quick.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of options. Try InfoCaptor, it is free https://my.infocaptor.com

huge visualization library and connects to social analytics as well as databases

PS: I am the developer